# Please teach me why datatable column search with regex don't return anything

Tags: datatables

This is my problem:

**Return right rows→**

```
table.column( 2 ).search('aaa').draw();
```

**Don't return anything→**

```
table.column( 2 ).search('aaa|bbb', true, false ).draw();
```

**I'm using these settings of datatable↓**

```
        scrollY:        "350px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,

        "ajax": {
            "url": "djangoviews",
            "type": "GET",
            //"success" : back
        },
        searching: true,
        //fixedHeader: true,
        responsive: false,
        fixedColumns: true,
        "search": {
            "regex": true
          },
```

I'm using severprocessing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please remember to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre]. Specifically, a full datatable definition, plus some sample data which we can use to recreate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

finally I find the reasen.
when I use serverSide option on datatable settings.
column regex search goes don't work.

But why... I really don't know about it.
and other people may be same situation.

I want to discus about it...